# Pass php array to ajax

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I have this array:

```
    $users = array();
// Finally, loop over the results
foreach( $select as $email => $ip )
{
    $users[$email] = $ip;
}
```

Now i want to pass this array to ajax and print in another script:

```
$html="<center><a href=\"#\" id=\"check_spam\" onclick=\"$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'mcheck.php', data:'users=$users', success: function(data){ $('#results').html(data);}});\">Check users for spam</a></center>";
```

mcheck.php

```
echo $_POST['users'];
```

This code does not work. How can i do this?

Comment: You can not pass array to ajax you have to convert it to json format and then you can pass

Comment: yes json_encode - will help you here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Sergiu Costas pointer out, the best way is to JSON encode it and then decode, but you can also try:

```
$html="<center><a href=\"#\" id=\"check_spam\" onclick=\"$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'mcheck.php', data: '" . http_build_query(array('users' => $users)) . "', success: function(data){ $('#results').html(data);}});\">Check users for spam</a></center>";
```

If your $users array is:

```
$users = array( array('email' => 'a@email.com'), array('email' => 'b@email.com')));
```

then `http_build_query('users' => $users)` will generate:

```
users%5B0%5D%5Bemail%5D=a%40email.com&users%5B1%5D%5Bemail%5D=b%40email.com
```

which is the url-encoded version of:

```
 users[0][email]=a@email.com&users[1][email]=b@email.com
```

which will be decoded back to array in mcheck.php

Answer (score 2):

The Best way is to encode array into JSON format.

In PHP:

```
$users_json = json_encode($users);
```

// To decode in javascript

```
var obj = JSON.parse(json_str);
```

Answer (score 0):

if u want to pass php array to js you can `json_encode` the array to do that.

```
$html="<center><a href=\"#\" id=\"check_spam\" onclick=\"$.ajax({type: 'POST', url: 'mcheck.php', data:'users=".json_encode($users)."', success: function(data){ $('#results').html(data);}});\">Check users for spam</a></center>";
```